# Efficient way to drop rows with overlapping times

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a long dataset with columns representing start and stop times, and I want to drop a row if it overlaps with another and has a higher priority (eg 1 is the highest priority). My example data is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
times_df <- tibble(start = as_datetime(c("2019-10-05 14:05:25", 
    "2019-10-05 17:30:20", 
    "2019-10-05 17:37:00", 
    "2019-10-06 04:43:55", 
    "2019-10-06 04:53:45")), 
    stop = as_datetime(c("2019-10-05 14:19:20",
    "2019-10-05 17:45:15", 
    "2019-10-05 17:50:45", 
    "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
    "2019-10-06 05:07:10")), priority = c(5,3,4,3,4))
```

The way I've come up with attacks the problem backwards by finding the overlaps with a higher priority value and then using an `anti_join` to remove them from the original dataframe. This code doesn't work if there are three periods overlapping the same timepoint and I'm sure there's a more efficient and functional way to do this.

```
dropOverlaps <- function(df) {
    drops <- df %>% 
        filter(stop > lead(start) | lag(stop) > start) %>% 
        mutate(group = ({seq(1, nrow(.)/2)} %>% 
        rep(each=2))) %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        filter(priority == max(priority))
    anti_join(df, drops)
}

dropOverlaps(times_df)
#> Joining, by = c("start", "stop", "priority")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   start               stop                priority
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>
#> 1 2019-10-05 14:05:25 2019-10-05 14:19:20        5
#> 2 2019-10-05 17:30:20 2019-10-05 17:45:15        3
#> 3 2019-10-06 04:43:55 2019-10-06 04:59:00        3
```

Can anyone help me get the same output but with a cleaner function? Bonus if it can handle an input with three or more time periods that all overlap.

Comment: If you want you can check all the combinations with `combn`, though it can get expensive if you've got a lot of rows. `times_df %>% mutate(interval = interval(start, stop)) %>% {combn(nrow(.), 2, function(x) if (int_overlaps(.$interval[x[1]], .$interval[x[2]])) x[which.min(.$priority[x])], simplify = FALSE)} %>% unlist() %>% {slice(times_df, -.)}`

Comment: You might try messing around `plyranges` which adapts IRanges/GRanges (used to find overlaps across genomes) for the tidyverse. I think you could transform your times into "genomic" ranges by converting your days + hours into an hours integer ("choromosome") and your minutes + seconds into a seconds integer ("nucleotides"). If you looked at the output of `pair_overlaps` (and used an ID column to remove for self-self overlaps), you could keep your priority and do a nice filter of the results + inner_join with your original table. It's hacky but should optimize ease of coding + efficiency.

Comment: Or you can simply use IRanges with datetimes converted to numbers. An example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647177/find-all-date-ranges-for-overlapping-start-and-end-dates-in-r

Comment: I just came across data.table::foverlaps and this would be a better solution than the genomic tools I suggested. I don't have time to work out the logic of what to keep, but it should be solvable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution using `foverlaps` to detect the overlapping records (as already mentioned by @GenesRus).
The overlapping records are assigned to groups to filter the record with max. priority in the group. I added two more records to your example data, to show that this procedure is also working for three or more overlapping records:

**Edit:** I modified and translated @pgcudahy's solution to `data.table` which gives even faster code:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

times_df <- data.frame(
  start = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:05:25",
      "2019-10-05 17:30:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:37:00",
      "2019-10-06 04:43:55",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:46",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:47"
    )
  ),
  stop = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:19:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:45:15",
      "2019-10-05 17:50:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:10",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:11",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:12"
    )
  ),
  priority = c(5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)

resultDT <- setDT(times_df, key="start")[!(stop >= shift(start, type="lead", fill = TRUE) & priority > shift(priority, type="lead", fill = TRUE)) &
                                         !(start <= shift(stop, type="lag", fill = FALSE) & priority > shift(priority, type="lag", fill = TRUE))]

# old approach ------------------------------------------------------------
# times_dt <- as.data.table(times_df)
# setkey(times_dt, start, stop)[, index := .I]
# overlaps_dt <- foverlaps(times_dt, times_dt, type = "any", which = TRUE)[xid != yid][, group := fifelse(xid > yid, yes = paste0(yid, "_", xid), no = paste0(xid, "_", yid))]
# overlaps_merged <- merge(times_dt, overlaps_dt, by.x = "index", by.y = "xid")[, .(delete_index = index[priority == max(priority)]), by = "group"]
# result_dt <- times_dt[!unique(overlaps_merged$delete_index)][, index := NULL]
```

For further details please see `?foverlaps` - There are some more useful features implemented to control what is considered a overlap such as `maxgap`, `minoverlap` or `type` (any, within, start, end and equal).

---

**Update - new benchmark**

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr       min         lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
          Paul 25572.550 26105.2710 30183.930 26514.342 29614.272 153810.600   100
           MKa  5100.447  5276.8350  6508.333  5401.275  5832.270  23137.879   100
      pgcudahy  3330.243  3474.4345  4284.640  3556.802  3748.203  21241.260   100
 ismirsehregal   711.084   913.3475  1144.829  1013.096  1433.427   2316.159   100
```

Benchmark code:

```
#### library ----

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

#### data ----

times_df <- data.frame(
  start = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:05:25",
      "2019-10-05 17:30:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:37:00",
      "2019-10-06 04:43:55",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:46",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:47"
    )
  ),
  stop = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:19:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:45:15",
      "2019-10-05 17:50:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:10",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:11",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:12"
    )
  ),
  priority = c(5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)

times_tib <- as_tibble(times_df)
times_dt <- as.data.table(times_df)

#### group_interval function ----

# buffer to take a form similar to: days(1), weeks(2), etc.
group_interval <- function(start, end, buffer = 0) {

  dat <- tibble(rid = 1:length(start),
                start = start,
                end = end,
                intervals = case_when(!is.na(start) & !is.na(end) ~ interval(start, end),
                                      is.na(start) ~ interval(end, end),
                                      is.na(end) ~ interval(start, start),
                                      TRUE ~ interval(NA, NA)))

  # apply buffer period to intervals
  int_start(dat$intervals) <- int_start(dat$intervals) - buffer + seconds(0.01)
  int_end(dat$intervals) <- int_end(dat$intervals) + buffer - seconds(0.01)

  df_overlap <- bind_cols(
    expand.grid(dat$rid, dat$rid), # make a 2 col table with every combination of id numbers
    expand.grid(dat$intervals, dat$intervals)) %>% # make a combination of every interval
    mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(.data$Var11, .data$Var21)) %>% # determine if intervals overlap
    rename("row" = "Var1", "col" = "Var2")

  # Find groups via graph theory See igraph package
  dat_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(filter(df_overlap, overlap) %>% select(row, col))
  groups <- components(dat_graph)$membership[df_overlap$row]

  # create a 2 column df with row (index) and group number, arrange on row number and return distinct values
  df_groups <- tibble(row = as.integer(names(groups)), group = groups) %>%
    unique()

  # returns
  left_join(select(dat, rid), df_groups, by = c("rid" = "row"))$group

}

#### benchmark ----

library(igraph)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)

df_Paul <- df_MKa <- df_pgcudahy <- df_ismirsehregal <- times_df <- data.frame(
  start = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:05:25",
      "2019-10-05 17:30:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:37:00",
      "2019-10-06 04:43:55",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:46",
      "2019-10-07 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00")
  ),
  stop = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:19:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:45:15",
      "2019-10-05 17:50:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:10",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:11",
      "2019-10-07 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00")
  ),
  priority = c(5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
)


benchmarks <- microbenchmark(Paul = {
  group_interval <- function(start, end, buffer = 0) {

    dat <- tibble(rid = 1:length(start),
                  start = start,
                  end = end,
                  intervals = case_when(!is.na(start) & !is.na(end) ~ interval(start, end),
                                        is.na(start) ~ interval(end, end),
                                        is.na(end) ~ interval(start, start),
                                        TRUE ~ interval(NA, NA)))

    int_start(dat$intervals) <- int_start(dat$intervals) - buffer + seconds(0.01)
    int_end(dat$intervals) <- int_end(dat$intervals) + buffer - seconds(0.01)

    df_overlap <- bind_cols(
      expand.grid(dat$rid, dat$rid), # make a 2 col table with every combination of id numbers
      expand.grid(dat$intervals, dat$intervals)) %>% # make a combination of every interval
      mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(.data$Var11, .data$Var21)) %>% # determine if intervals overlap
      rename("row" = "Var1", "col" = "Var2")

    dat_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(filter(df_overlap, overlap) %>% select(row, col))
    groups <- components(dat_graph)$membership[df_overlap$row]

    df_groups <- tibble(row = as.integer(names(groups)), group = groups) %>%
      unique()

    left_join(select(dat, rid), df_groups, by = c("rid" = "row"))$group
  }

  times_tib <- as_tibble(df_Paul)

  mutate(times_tib, group = group_interval(start, stop)) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    top_n(1, desc(priority)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-group)
},
MKa = {
  df_MKa$id <- 1:nrow(df_MKa)

  # Create consolidated df which we will use to check if stop date is in between start and stop
  my_df <- bind_rows(replicate(n = nrow(df_MKa), expr = df_MKa, simplify = FALSE))
  my_df$stop_chk <- rep(df_MKa$stop, each = nrow(df_MKa))

  # Flag if stop date sits in between start and stop
  my_df$chk <- my_df$stop_chk >= my_df$start & my_df$stop_chk <= my_df$stop
  my_df$chk_id <- df_MKa[match(my_df$stop_chk, df_MKa$stop), "id"]

  # Using igrpah to cluster ids to create unique groups
  # this will identify any overlapping groups
  library(igraph)
  g <- graph.data.frame(my_df[my_df$chk == TRUE, c("id", "chk_id")])
  df_g <- data.frame(clusters(g)$membership)
  df_g$chk_id <- row.names(df_g)

  # copy the unique groups to the df
  my_df$new_id <- df_g[match(my_df$chk_id, df_g$chk_id), "clusters.g..membership"]
  my_df %>% 
    filter(chk == TRUE) %>%
    arrange(priority) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(new_id)) %>%
    select(start, stop, priority) %>%
    arrange(start)
}, pgcudahy = {
  df_pgcudahy %>%
    arrange(start) %>%
    mutate(remove1 = ifelse((stop >= lead(start, default=FALSE)) & 
                              (priority > lead(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    mutate(remove2 = ifelse((start <= lag(stop, default=FALSE)) & 
                              (priority > lag(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    filter(remove1 == FALSE & remove2 == FALSE) %>%
    select(1:3)
}, ismirsehregal = {
  setDT(df_ismirsehregal, key="start")[!(stop >= shift(start, type="lead", fill = TRUE) & priority > shift(priority, type="lead", fill = TRUE)) &
                                       !(start <= shift(stop, type="lag", fill = FALSE) & priority > shift(priority, type="lag", fill = TRUE))]
})

benchmarks
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a helper function that groups overlapping data/time data using the igraph package (it can include an overlap buffer, i.e. terminus are within 1 minute ...)

I used it to group your data based on intervals in lubridate, then do some data-wrangling to get only the top priority entry from overlapping times.

I'm not sure how well it will scale.

```
#### library ----

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(igraph)

#### data ----

times_df <- tibble(start = as_datetime(c("2019-10-05 14:05:25", 
                                         "2019-10-05 17:30:20", 
                                         "2019-10-05 17:37:00", 
                                         "2019-10-06 04:43:55", 
                                         "2019-10-06 04:53:45")), 
                   stop = as_datetime(c("2019-10-05 14:19:20",
                                        "2019-10-05 17:45:15", 
                                        "2019-10-05 17:50:45", 
                                        "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
                                        "2019-10-06 05:07:10")), priority = c(5,3,4,3,4))

#### group_interval function ----

# buffer to take a form similar to: days(1), weeks(2), etc.
group_interval <- function(start, end, buffer = 0) {

  dat <- tibble(rid = 1:length(start),
                start = start,
                end = end,
                intervals = case_when(!is.na(start) & !is.na(end) ~ interval(start, end),
                                      is.na(start) ~ interval(end, end),
                                      is.na(end) ~ interval(start, start),
                                      TRUE ~ interval(NA, NA)))

  # apply buffer period to intervals
  int_start(dat$intervals) <- int_start(dat$intervals) - buffer + seconds(0.01)
  int_end(dat$intervals) <- int_end(dat$intervals) + buffer - seconds(0.01)

  df_overlap <- bind_cols(
    expand.grid(dat$rid, dat$rid), # make a 2 col table with every combination of id numbers
    expand.grid(dat$intervals, dat$intervals)) %>% # make a combination of every interval
    mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(.data$Var11, .data$Var21)) %>% # determine if intervals overlap
    rename("row" = "Var1", "col" = "Var2")

  # Find groups via graph theory See igraph package
  dat_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(filter(df_overlap, overlap) %>% select(row, col))
  groups <- components(dat_graph)$membership[df_overlap$row]

  # create a 2 column df with row (index) and group number, arrange on row number and return distinct values
  df_groups <- tibble(row = as.integer(names(groups)), group = groups) %>%
    unique()

  # returns
  left_join(select(dat, rid), df_groups, by = c("rid" = "row"))$group

}

#### data munging ----

mutate(times_df, group = group_interval(start, stop)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  top_n(1, desc(priority)) %>% # not sure why desc is needed, but top_n was giving the lower 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
```

Which gives:

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 3
      start               stop                priority
      <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl>
    1 2019-10-05 14:05:25 2019-10-05 14:19:20        5
    2 2019-10-05 17:30:20 2019-10-05 17:45:15        3
    3 2019-10-06 04:43:55 2019-10-06 04:59:00        3
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using `igraph` to identify any overlapping groups, you could try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
times_df <- data.frame(
  start = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:05:25",
      "2019-10-05 17:30:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:37:00",
      "2019-10-06 04:43:55",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:46",
      "2019-10-07 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00")
  ),
  stop = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:19:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:45:15",
      "2019-10-05 17:50:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:10",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:11",
      "2019-10-07 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00")
  ),
  priority = c(5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
)
times_df$id <- 1:nrow(times_df)


# Create consolidated df which we will use to check if stop date is in between start and stop
my_df <- bind_rows(replicate(n = nrow(times_df), expr = times_df, simplify = FALSE))
my_df$stop_chk <- rep(times_df$stop, each = nrow(times_df))

# Flag if stop date sits in between start and stop
my_df$chk <- my_df$stop_chk >= my_df$start & my_df$stop_chk <= my_df$stop
my_df$chk_id <- times_df[match(my_df$stop_chk, times_df$stop), "id"]

# Using igrpah to cluster ids to create unique groups
# this will identify any overlapping groups
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(my_df[my_df$chk == TRUE, c("id", "chk_id")])
df_g <- data.frame(clusters(g)$membership)
df_g$chk_id <- row.names(df_g)

# copy the unique groups to the df
my_df$new_id <- df_g[match(my_df$chk_id, df_g$chk_id), "clusters.g..membership"]
my_df %>% 
  filter(chk == TRUE) %>%
  arrange(priority) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(new_id)) %>%
  select(start, stop, priority) %>%
  arrange(start)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went down a rabbit hole looking at interval trees (and R implementations like IRanges / plyranges) but I think this problem doesn't need such an involved data structure since the start times can be easily sorted. I also expanded the test set like @ismirsehregal to cover more potential [interval relations](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~alspaugh/cls/shr/allen.html) such as an interval that starts before and ends after its neighbor, or when three intervals overlap but the first and last don't overlap each other, or two intervals that start and stop at exactly the same times.

```
library(lubridate)
times_df <- data.frame(
  start = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:05:25",
      "2019-10-05 17:30:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:37:00",
      "2019-10-06 04:43:55",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:53:46",
      "2019-10-07 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:00:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:10:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:20:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:00:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:10:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:00:00")
  ),
  stop = as_datetime(
    c(
      "2019-10-05 14:19:20",
      "2019-10-05 17:45:15",
      "2019-10-05 17:50:45",
      "2019-10-06 04:59:00",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:10",
      "2019-10-06 05:07:11",
      "2019-10-07 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-07 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:18:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:28:00",
      "2019-10-08 06:38:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-09 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:30:00",
      "2019-10-10 03:20:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00",
      "2019-10-11 05:40:00")
  ),
  priority = c(5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4)
)
```

I then make two passes through each interval to see if it overlaps with its predecessor or successor

`stop >= lead(start, default=FALSE)` and `start <= lag(stop, default=FALSE))`

During each pass, there's a second check to see if the interval's priority has a higher numeric value than the predecessor or successor `priority > lead(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))`. During each pass, if both conditions are true, a "remove" flag is set to true in a new column using `mutate`. Any rows with a remove flag are then filtered.

```
library(tidyverse)
times_df %>%
    arrange(start) %>%
    mutate(remove1 = ifelse((stop >= lead(start, default=FALSE)) & 
                            (priority > lead(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), 
                            TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    mutate(remove2 = ifelse((start <= lag(stop, default=FALSE)) & 
                            (priority > lag(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), 
                            TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    filter(remove1 == FALSE & remove2 == FALSE) %>%
    select(1:3)
```

This avoids checking all potential combinations of intervals like @Paul's answer (2n versus n! comparisons) as well as accomodates my ignorance of graph theory :)

Similarly @ismirsehregal's answer has data.table magic that is beyond my comprehension.

@MKa's solution doesn't seem to work with >2 overlapping periods

Testing the solutions gives

```
#>          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
#> 1 dplyr_igraph 36.568842 41.510950 46.692147 43.362724 47.065277 241.92073
#> 2  data.table  9.126385  9.935049 11.395977 10.521032 11.446257  34.26953
#> 3       dplyr  5.031397  5.500363  6.224059  5.902589  6.373197  15.09273
#>   neval
#> 1   100
#> 2   100
#> 3   100
```

From this code

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
benchmarks <- microbenchmark(dplyr_igraph = {
  group_interval <- function(start, end, buffer = 0) {

  dat <- tibble(rid = 1:length(start),
                start = start,
                end = end,
                intervals = case_when(!is.na(start) & !is.na(end) ~ interval(start, end),
                                      is.na(start) ~ interval(end, end),
                                      is.na(end) ~ interval(start, start),
                                      TRUE ~ interval(NA, NA)))

  int_start(dat$intervals) <- int_start(dat$intervals) - buffer + seconds(0.01)
  int_end(dat$intervals) <- int_end(dat$intervals) + buffer - seconds(0.01)

  df_overlap <- bind_cols(
    expand.grid(dat$rid, dat$rid), # make a 2 col table with every combination of id numbers
    expand.grid(dat$intervals, dat$intervals)) %>% # make a combination of every interval
    mutate(overlap = int_overlaps(.data$Var11, .data$Var21)) %>% # determine if intervals overlap
    rename("row" = "Var1", "col" = "Var2")

  dat_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(filter(df_overlap, overlap) %>% select(row, col))
  groups <- components(dat_graph)$membership[df_overlap$row]

  df_groups <- tibble(row = as.integer(names(groups)), group = groups) %>%
    unique()

  left_join(select(dat, rid), df_groups, by = c("rid" = "row"))$group
  }

  times_tib <- as_tibble(times_df)

  mutate(times_tib, group = group_interval(start, stop)) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    top_n(1, desc(priority)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-group)
}, data.table = {
  times_dt <- as.data.table(times_df)
  setkey(times_dt, start, stop)[, index := .I]
  overlaps_dt <- foverlaps(times_dt, times_dt, type = "any", which = TRUE)[xid != yid][, group := fifelse(xid > yid, yes = paste0(yid, "_", xid), no = paste0(xid, "_", yid))]
  overlaps_merged <- merge(times_dt, overlaps_dt, by.x = "index", by.y = "xid")[, .(delete_index = index[priority == max(priority)]), by = "group"]
  result_dt <- times_dt[!unique(overlaps_merged$delete_index)][, index := NULL]
}, dplyr = {
times_df %>%
    arrange(start) %>%
    mutate(remove1 = ifelse((stop >= lead(start, default=FALSE)) & 
                            (priority > lead(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    mutate(remove2 = ifelse((start <= lag(stop, default=FALSE)) & 
                            (priority > lag(priority, default=(max(priority) + 1))), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    filter(remove1 == FALSE & remove2 == FALSE) %>%
    select(1:3)
})
summary(benchmarks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I wasn't familiar with the `tibble` structure and looks like `pull()` was causing the issue. For `dataframe()`, it should work as is. Just updated the answer.

Comment: Nice approach, I took your logic, modified it a little and translated it to `data.table` which makes things even faster (please check my new benchmark).