# Calculating overlapping dates in R (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a dataset of individuals (CSN), each of whom has had anywhere from zero to multiple interventions performed during a hospital admission (in this case, central lines placed), each with a start and an end date. I am trying to generate a new date range that will calculate any overlapping dates. In other words, I'm trying to calculate the total date range when an individual had a central line in place.

Data for example:

```
structure(list(CSN_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), First_day = structure(c(1514937600, 
1514937600, 1515024000, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515974400, 1516147200, 
1516147200, 1516147200, 1516233600, 1516233600, 1517097600, 1517097600, 
1517702400, 1517356800, 1518220800, 1519257600, 1519948800, 1520812800, 
1521504000, 1522022400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Last_day = structure(c(1515628800, 1515110400, 1515542400, 
1515542400, 1515628800, 1516579200, 1516320000, 1517184000, 1516233600, 
1517184000, 1517702400, 1517184000, 1517616000, 1517702400, 1518220800, 
1518825600, 1519689600, 1520812800, 1521763200, 1522108800, 1522108800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ideally, the output would return a single date range for all overlapping dates, but if there were a stretch of days that are missed by each, then a new interval would be created. So, for group 1, rows 1-5 would all have start = 2018-01-03 and end = 2018-01-11, but then row 6 would have start = 2018-01-15 and end = 2018-01-22.

I've tried to do the following:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(CSN_id, First_day) %>% 
  mutate(First_day = ymd(First_day),
         Last_day = ymd(Last_day),
         start = ymd("1970-01-01"),
         end = ymd("1970-01-01")) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(test = if_else(row_number() == 1, interval(First_day, Last_day), interval(lag(start), lag(end))),
         start = if_else(row_number() == 1, First_day,
                         if_else(First_day <= lag(end), lag(First_day), First_day)),
         end = if_else(row_number() == 1, Last_day,
                       if_else(Last_day %within% lag(test) == TRUE, lag(end), Last_day)))
```

However, I don't think the lag function is working as intended, and it always returns Last_day for some reason. I tried getting rid of rowwise, but then the intervals get messed up (persistently stuck in 1970s).

The output I'm getting is:

```
structure(list(CSN_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), First_day = structure(c(17534, 
17534, 17535, 17535, 17536, 17546, 17548, 17548, 17548, 17549, 
17549, 17559, 17559, 17566, 17562, 17572, 17584, 17592, 17602, 
17610, 17616), class = "Date"), Last_day = structure(c(17542, 
17536, 17541, 17541, 17542, 17553, 17550, 17560, 17549, 17560, 
17566, 17560, 17565, 17566, 17572, 17579, 17589, 17602, 17613, 
17617, 17617), class = "Date"), start = structure(c(17534, 17534, 
17535, 17535, 17536, 17546, 17548, 17548, 17548, 17549, 17549, 
17559, 17559, 17566, 17562, 17572, 17584, 17592, 17602, 17610, 
17616), class = "Date"), end = structure(c(17542, 17536, 17541, 
17541, 17542, 17553, 17550, 17560, 17549, 17560, 17566, 17560, 
17565, 17566, 17572, 17579, 17589, 17602, 17613, 17617, 17617
), class = "Date"), test = new("Interval", .Data = c(691200, 
172800, 518400, 518400, 518400, 604800, 172800, 1036800, 86400, 
950400, 1468800, 86400, 518400, 0, 864000, 604800, 432000, 864000, 
950400, 604800, 86400), start = structure(c(1514937600, 1514937600, 
1515024000, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515974400, 1516147200, 1516147200, 
1516147200, 1516233600, 1516233600, 1517097600, 1517097600, 1517702400, 
1517356800, 1518220800, 1519257600, 1519948800, 1520812800, 1521504000, 
1522022400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    tzone = "UTC")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), groups = structure(list(
    CSN_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using the [`IRanges` package on Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html). The `collapse_date_ranges` function is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718415/15293191), and I just adjusted according

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

collapse_date_ranges <- function(w, min.gapwidth = 1L) {
  IRanges::IRanges(start = as.integer(as.Date(w$First_day)), 
                   end = as.integer(as.Date(w$Last_day))) %>% 
    IRanges::reduce(min.gapwidth = min.gapwidth) %>% 
    as.data.table() %>% 
    .[, lapply(.SD, lubridate::as_date),
      .SDcols = c("start", "end")]
}


split(df, df$CSN_id) %>% 
  map(., ~collapse_date_ranges(., 0L)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = 'id')
```

**Output**

```
   id      start        end
1:  1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
2:  1 2018-01-15 2018-01-22
3:  2 2018-01-17 2018-01-19
4:  3 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
5:  4 2018-01-31 2018-02-17
6:  4 2018-02-22 2018-02-27
7:  4 2018-03-02 2018-03-27
```

If you want to have this in the original dataframe, then we can join the data back to the original dataframe, then use `fill` to add the dates to each row.

```
split(df, df$CSN_id) %>% 
  map(., ~collapse_date_ranges(., 0L)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., .id = 'CSN_id2') %>% 
  data.frame %>% 
  mutate(CSN_id2 = as.integer(CSN_id2)) %>% 
  full_join(df, ., by = c("CSN_id" = "CSN_id2", "First_day" = "start"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-CSN_id2) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id) %>% 
  fill(start, end, .direction = "down")
```

*Output*

```
   CSN_id First_day           Last_day            start      end       
    <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <date>     <date>    
 1      1 2018-01-03 00:00:00 2018-01-11 00:00:00 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 2      1 2018-01-03 00:00:00 2018-01-05 00:00:00 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 3      1 2018-01-04 00:00:00 2018-01-10 00:00:00 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 4      1 2018-01-04 00:00:00 2018-01-10 00:00:00 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 5      1 2018-01-05 00:00:00 2018-01-11 00:00:00 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 6      1 2018-01-15 00:00:00 2018-01-22 00:00:00 2018-01-15 2018-01-22
 7      2 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-01-19 00:00:00 2018-01-17 2018-01-19
 8      3 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-01-29 00:00:00 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
 9      3 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-01-18 00:00:00 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
10      3 2018-01-18 00:00:00 2018-01-29 00:00:00 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
# … with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw some of the questions referencing IRanges and I spent some time trying it but had trouble mapping it to my question. This seems to work quite well. As I was applying it to the larger dataset, I got NA's in some rows but I think I solved it by arranging the dataset first by CSN_id and First_day. I'm not sure if that makes sense but I'll try it on a few more snippets of the data to verify. Thanks again!

Comment: @djd02007 Yeah, I think it is dependent upon the data being in order. But you will get NAs when doing the `left_join` as I just join it on the start date, then just `fill` in the rest of the values for `start` and `end`. I'd imagine that it is probably quicker than `tidyverse`, but obviously it's a little more complicated to follow. There's always a tradeoff somewhere! You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what your desired output is, but you can try this approach:

```
dat %>% 
  arrange(CSN_id,First_day,Last_day) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id, First_day) %>%
  summarize(Last_day=max(Last_day,na.rm=T)) %>% 
  mutate(interval=as.numeric(First_day- lag(Last_day))>0,
         interval=cumsum(if_else(is.na(interval),FALSE,interval))+1) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id,interval) %>% 
  summarize(start = min(First_day),
         end = max(Last_day))
```

Output:

```
  CSN_id interval start               end                
   <int>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1      1        1 2018-01-03 00:00:00 2018-01-11 00:00:00
2      1        2 2018-01-15 00:00:00 2018-01-22 00:00:00
3      2        1 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-01-19 00:00:00
4      3        1 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-02-04 00:00:00
5      3        2 2018-02-04 00:00:00 2018-02-04 00:00:00
6      4        1 2018-01-31 00:00:00 2018-02-17 00:00:00
7      4        2 2018-02-22 00:00:00 2018-02-27 00:00:00
8      4        3 2018-03-02 00:00:00 2018-03-27 00:00:00
```

If you prefer to retain all the original rows, and all the dates are dates and not datetimes, you could also do something like this:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(First_day:Last_day, ~as.Date(.x))) %>% 
  arrange(CSN_id,First_day,Last_day) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id) %>%
  mutate(interval=as.numeric(First_day- lag(Last_day))>0,
         interval=cumsum(if_else(is.na(interval),FALSE,interval))+1) %>% 
  group_by(CSN_id,interval) %>% 
  mutate(start = min(First_day),
            end = max(Last_day))
```

Output:

```
   CSN_id First_day  Last_day   interval start      end       
    <int> <date>     <date>        <dbl> <date>     <date>    
 1      1 2018-01-03 2018-01-05        1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 2      1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11        1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 3      1 2018-01-04 2018-01-10        1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 4      1 2018-01-04 2018-01-10        1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 5      1 2018-01-05 2018-01-11        1 2018-01-03 2018-01-11
 6      1 2018-01-15 2018-01-22        2 2018-01-15 2018-01-22
 7      2 2018-01-17 2018-01-19        1 2018-01-17 2018-01-19
 8      3 2018-01-17 2018-01-18        1 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
 9      3 2018-01-17 2018-01-29        1 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
10      3 2018-01-18 2018-01-29        1 2018-01-17 2018-02-04
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: Awesome! Yeah this would definitely work. I have to parse through it to see how you did it but I can definitely work with this. Ultimately I want to preserve the number of rows and add a new variable that will be the max # days between any start and end within that CSN_id but with this table I could easily pull it back in, I think. Thank you so much for the quick response!